# Generate macros from names defined by list

Tags: makefile

I have this definitions in Makefile:

```
PREFIX = PRE
POSTFIXES = POST1 POST2 POST3
```

Now I would like to generate programmatically the following macros:

```
NAME_1 = PRE_POST1
NAME_2 = PRE_POST2
NAME_3 = PRE_POST3
#...
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want assuming `NAME_#` was literal.

```
$(foreach f,$(POSTFIXES),$(eval NAME_$(subst POST,,$f) = $(PREFIX)_$f))
```

Result:

```
NAME_1 = PRE_POST1
NAME_2 = PRE_POST2
NAME_3 = PRE_POST3
```

Explanation:

- Remove `POST` from each postfix leaving just the number: `$(subst POST,,$f)`
- Concatenate `NAME_` with the number from the previous step: `NAME_$(subst POST,,$f)`
- Concatenate `$(PREFIX)` and the current postfix to create the desired value string: `$(PREFIX)_$f`
- Use `$(eval)` to assign the value to the computed variable name: `$(eval NAME_$(subst POST,,$f) = $(PREFIX)_$f)`
- Do that all for each postfix in the list: `$(foreach f,$(POSTFIXES),$(eval NAME_$(subst POST,,$f) = $(PREFIX)_$f))`

Update for sequential `NAME_#` variables unrelated to `POSTFIXES` values:

make doesn't do math, at all really, so you need to play games to "count". (Thanks to the fantastic [GMSL](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/) for showing me this trick.)

```
POSTFIXES = POST_X POST_Y POST_Z

N := x
$(foreach f,$(POSTFIXES),$(eval NAME_$(words $N) = $(PREFIX)_$f)$(eval N += x))
```

Result:

```
NAME_1 = PRE_POST_X
NAME_2 = PRE_POST_Y
NAME_3 = PRE_POST_Z
```

Comment: Your answer is great and gave me some direction. What if we do some more general `POSTFIXES = POST_X POST_Y POST_Z` and want generate macros like `NAME_1 = PRE_POST_X` ... (still with literal NAME_#, but not dependent from postfix name). Can we do that without `for` loop?